# How long does unrefrigerated shredded cheese last?

Tags: storage-lifetime, cheese

I left an unopened package of shredded mozarella cheese out unrefrigerated last night after going grocery shopping, and found it today, 16 hours later. Should I toss it?

Comment: Well, it depends on what kind of cheese. Some types of cheese can go without refrigeration almost infinitely, while other types of cheese spoil much quicker. Most cheeses will be fine after just sixteen hours out of the fridge, but just to be sure: please define your cheese! :)

Comment: (Also, it depends on the temperature at your house. Some cheeses might get a little sweaty if kept above about 70°F for too long)

Comment: I wonder how people had cheese before frdges

Comment: Personally, I'd toss it - a solid block, sure, but shredded has a lot more surface area. If it is sealed, it probably ain't gonna kill you, but why mess around?

Comment: Personally, I'd smell it. Cheese tends to smell bad first.

Comment: @mbg - we'd all have had cellars :)

Answer (score 3):

No, it's fine.
It wasn't opened or anything? Then nothing is wrong with it.
If you already opened it, smell it.

Comment: It is fine... Just trust the internet! :)